# Why does the Python import statement not use parentheses?

Tags: python, import, keyword

I understand the concept of keywords as reserved words in Python that should not be used as identifiers. What is confusing to me is that other than that commonality, keywords appear to me to be used differently. For example the import and del statements seem to work as functions that only take one parameter, whereas other keywords such as if and while are used to make compound statements. My question is if certain keywords (e.g. import) are used in the same manner as a function, then why is the syntax different (i.e. no parenthesis is used). print being used as a function as opposed to it's previous use as a keyword is much more intuitive to me. This can be confusing to a new learner whose first statement is usually import, the syntax of which is seemingly analogous to an irregular verb in human languages.

Comment: Where did you see `import` and `del` used in the same manner as a function? that observation is wrong

Comment: Seems like an unanswerable psychological question. Why didn't they use `$` to denote variables and why omit braces? It's just a design decision.

Comment: keywords are handled during parsing, with each having its own requirements, as outlined at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html.  Apart from the basic calling syntax (`name(....)`) functions are handled at runtime.  There is an `importlib` if you need/want to perform import with a function syntax, https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html.  keyword statements may be executed via function calls, such as `__import__', https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing binds names and deleting unbinds names, so these need to be statements.

The simple reason that `import` and `del` cannot be functions, is that a function cannot add/remove from the calling namespace. The body of a function does not really have access to the caller namespace (except with some implementation-specific frame hacks).

> Note that because of its semantics, `del` *can't* be a function: `del a` deletes `a` from the current namespace. A function can't delete something from the calling namespace

– [Guido van Rossum, 1 Aug 1994](http://quotations.amk.ca/python-quotes/#q20)

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking too hard. There are functions which can import, but the statement `import` simplifies the implementation (for us users). Consider, if it were (only) a function, you'd have to quote the string.. `import('foo.py')`. Python2 `print` didn't really save much in the way of keystrokes.

If you want function functionality, it is available, consider the first paragraph in Python Language Reference.

> **5. The import system**
>
> Python code in one module gains access to the code in another module by the process of importing it. The import statement is the most common way of invoking the import machinery, but it is not the only way. Functions such as importlib.import_module() and built-in __import__() can also be used to invoke the import machinery.

Comment: Even worse - it would be `foo = import('foo.py')`.

Comment: Also, how would `from a import b` or similar statements work if import had function-like syntax?